# What is the purpose of the ECR Repository which is automatically create when bootstrapping with AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

What's the purpose of the ECR Repository which is automatically created when bootstrapping a stack through AWS CDK?  Am I suppose to push all Docker Images to it?  Can it be deleted?  I'm reading through docs on customizing values throughout the bootstrap process, but I haven't found why such a resource is automatically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository created during `bootstrap` is used e.g. when doing [`DockerImage.fromBuild`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.DockerImage.html). Because such repository exists and is not part of any stack that you define it may be easier to get started with it.

There are some downsides to it though. For example, because different kinds of images are pushed there it is harder to define a meaningful lifecycle policy. Moreover, because the image is built during a deployment it is possible that an image that was used for testing e.g. on stage will be different from the one deployed to prod.

Long term it's best to define a dedicated repository per application service deployed as part of your solution.